# How to reload current paginate page with updated record and deleted record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to ROR.   I am using **"will_paginate"** gem. Go the paginate working great.  In the controller, I have def for the "index", "edit", "create", "update", "destroy" (all standard view created by scaffold except "show").   From the index page, user can edit or delete a record from the list or add a new record.   Now, I need to
1.  after editing a record, in the "update", I want to be able to go back to the page where the record was, and reload the page with the updated info. for the record
2.  after deleted a record, in the "destroy", I want to be able to go back to the page where the record was.   The page should be reload without the deleted record
3.  after a new record add, I would like to show the page where the new record should be.

The main issue is really that I don't know how pass along the params[:pages] from one views to another and how to reload the paginate specific page.

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just just pass your request parameters directly to the `redirect_to`, like this:

```
redirect_to your_resources_path, :page => params[:page]
```

Comment: I did what you suggested in def update ..   format.html { redirect_to mypages_url, :page => params[:page] }.  However, it redirect to the first page.